# How to make a matplotlib screen fullscreen without hiding the taskbar

Tags: python, matplotlib

Let's say I have the following chunk of code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

manager = plt.get_current_fig_manager()
manager.full_screen_toggle()
plt.show()
```

The screen is set to be in fullscreen mode. My issue is that the taskbar is being hidden. How do I adjust the fullscreen mode so that it doesn't hide my taskbar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually use

```
mng = plt.get_current_fig_manager()
mng.frame.Maximize(True)
```

before the call to `plt.show()`, and I get a maximized window. This works for the 'wx' backend only.

Or try this,

```
wm = plt.get_current_fig_manager()
wm.window.state('zoomed')
```

Comment: I get the following error when I do that: AttributeError: 'FigureManagerTk' object has no attribute 'frame'

Comment: It works with backend wx, I've updated the post accordingly. Likely the Tk backend you are using doesn't support this feature. Do you have the option to change matplotlib backend to 'wx'?

Comment: `figManager = plt.get_current_fig_manager()`
`figManager.window.showMaximized()` Could you try this?

Comment: @L Prathyusha, It throws the following error: AttributeError: '_tkinter.tkapp' object has no attribute 'showMaximized'

Comment: Never mind, the updated part of your answer worked for me

Comment: Glad that worked! Could you give the reputation by clicking up arrow or accepting the answer? it'll be helpful

Comment: Yes, I will. It just didn't let me do it. It told me to wait a few minutes

Comment: There! I did both